# `aarch64-linux-musl-cross` has a broken link for `ld-musl-aarch64.so.1`

Tags: glibc, arm64

## The goal

I want to run an ARM64 Go binary on x86_64 Kali Linux using QEMU user mode.

## The problem

I got `aarch64-linux-musl-cross`.

```
~$ wget https://musl.cc/aarch64-linux-musl-cross.tgz
~$ tar -xvf aarch64-linux-musl-cross.tgz
```

I then used `~/aarch64-linux-musl-cross/bin/aarch64-linux-musl-gcc` to compile a simple hello world Go program. It compiled exactly as I wanted it to.

```
~/go_projects/bin$ file hello
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1, Go BuildID=-37pQ_4dEsp4pnAgj4QV/0unDR_0nE-A-DsF1SfKd/-8CRGAArG5J0XNspP2M-/u6ChmkaiRo9qoxEE15eo, not stripped
```

But, for some reason, the interpreter `~/aarch64-linux-musl-cross/aarch64-linux-musl/lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1` is a broken link to `/lib/libc.so`.

I have a file `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so` but it's just a text file.

```
~$ file /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so: ASCII text
~$ cat /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-littleaarch64)
GROUP ( /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6 /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 ) )
```

What is the link `ld-musl-aarch64.so.1` supposed to point to?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I found my answer right after posting this...

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y --no-install-recommends musl:arm64
ln -f -s /lib/aarch64-linux-musl/libc.so ~/aarch64-linux-musl-cross/aarch64-linux-musl/lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1
```